# Controlling number range in a colour scale matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have done a Graph using matplotlib and I would like to know how to control the scale in the colour bar and how to use just two numbers...

I am creating something like:

[image]

However I would like to have a scale bar from 0 to 2.5 using just the values [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5] and I would like to have just one decimal number like 2.5 and not 2.500 as it been used in the example above.

The source code to create this graph:

```
v = np.linspace(-0.001, 2.5, 15, endpoint=True)
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, v, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, v, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.xlabel("x (cm)")
plt.ylabel("z (cm)")
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

P.s.: Even using from 0 to 2.5 in v doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you try to use `plt.yticks()`? Example: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks

Answer (score 0):

Capture the colorbar object and then set the ticks to be what you want:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(...)
cb.set_ticks(tick_list)
```